# Unable to accept android Licenses for debugging and compiling .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio-code, archlinux

I have tried everything I could. Even the non-recomendable option of starting code as superuser and changing through chmod all the permissions at /opt/android-sdk folder. I also followed the instructions provided by VS Code about deleting and re-accepting the licenses. Everything I thought.

The thing is I actually agree to all licenses from the CLI. However, when accessing from VS Code, It is unable to either accept the licenses nor detect that they are already accepted. And when opening vscode as super user -don't ask me why- it's unable to detect MAUI SDK (but does detect .NET SDK... Mind blown)

I configured correctly the java SDK and the android SDK paths. I also reported a bug through github... I have no idea of what else to do (apart from changing again the permissions of /opt/android-sdk files, for security purposes...)

Anyone developing with C#/MAUI at archlinux (or any other Linux distro, don't care) who solved this deal?

Comment: cross-posted to multiple other sites: https://superuser.com/questions/1817736/unable-to-accept-android-licenses-for-debugging-and-compiling-net-maui , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/762003/unable-to-accept-android-licenses-for-debugging-and-compiling-net-maui

Answer (score -1):

you can check this [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/educator-developer-blog/net-maui-on-linux-with-visual-studio-code/ba-p/3982195) it worked for me with ubuntu.

Step 4 – Install Android Studio

This step is optional but highly recommended because it’s the easiest way to install three fundamental components for developing Android apps: the Android SDK, the SDK Manager, and Android emulators.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: edited. thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I actually did install Android Studio before posting my question, @Ez Fazary. 

Funny thing, I still had to give permissions to the folders where Android SDK is located (which is a VERY bad practice, since I did a chmod 777 to everything)

I don't consider a good solution having two IDEs installed just because one of them gives me problems it shouldn't give. It's very uncomfortable to build my project and change from one IDE to another just for debugging and executing code.

It's simply terrible.

I appreciate the time and effort it took your help, but I honestly hope VS Code do sthing